# Display Jalali (Shamsi) Date in Archive View

Tags: views, datetime

I have a Persian language website and I need to a archive block in my site.
but date of default archive view is Gregorian. I install Datex module and it convert all date of nodes to Jalali(Shamsi) Date but can't convert Gregorian date to Jalali Date in archive view.
I want to archive content in year+month format.
any one has another idea for convert date in archive view?

Answer (score 0):

you can use of [persoanTools](https://www.drupal.org/project/persiantools) module 
persian Tools change calender to jalali and you can use of it in archive and views pages

Answer (score 0):

to display jalali date in drupal, you can do one of the following :

1. install [persian tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/persiantools) and [Calendar Systems](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar_systems) and in node.tpl file write the following:

> ```
> <time datetime="<?php print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $node->created) ?>"><?php print $date ?></time>
> ```

2. get timestamp from php, convert it to javascript timestamp and display it using toLocalDateString():

> ```
> <time datetime="<?php print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $node->created); ?>">
>     <span class="publishedon">
>         <script>let pdate = new Date(<?php print $node->created.'000'; ?>).toLocaleDateString('fa-IR');  jQuery('.publishedon').text(pdate);</script>
>     </span>
> </time>
> ```